# Overriding <=> and equ? with different settings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

**Summary**: I'm trying to figure out a good way to store, sort, and average related data that I am grouping into objects after reading from a file.  I have two related questions:

1) Is it an acceptable practice to override `<=>` to sort objects in a different order while also overriding `equ?` to say that they are equal?

2) Is there a way to check a hash with `has_key?` where `has_key?` reads multiple arguments for performing and checking the hash?

**Details**:

I am reading in a large amount of data from a text file and I want to do operations on it where I sort it, and exclude the highest and lowest values, and compute an average.  To make this question more concrete my input sets consists of strings like:

`field1 field2 field3 value1 value2`

(note it is more complex but I've got the parsing working to extract these values already).

Initially I had created a class like:

```
class data
  def initialize
    @field1
    @field2
    @field3
    @value1
    @value2
  end
end
```

I also redefined the comparison operator `<=>` so that it sorts first on `field1` then `field2` and finally `field3`.  That allows me to print out all of the data sorted in the order that I want.

However now what I want to do is average together different values when all the fields are the same.  I also would like to be able to sort the entries and remove the highest and lowest values before doing the averaging.  That is I want to be able to group entries where `field1` `field2` and `field3` are the same.  Then sort those grouped entries by `value1` remove the highest and lowest entries and then average the remain results together.

One idea that I had is to extend the class definition to include an array that stores `value1` and `value2`.  Then I would insert the objects in a hash table and add new values to the object if the hash existed.  But I'm not sure how or if I can use multiple strings in checking whether a hash has a specific key.

I assume that I could override the `hash` and `equ?` operators so that objects with the same values for `field1` `field2` and `field3` would hash to the same location.  One thing I'm not sure about is whether it is a good idea to say that objects are equal with `equ?` but to have them sorted in a different order with `<=>`.

Or maybe there is a simpler way in Ruby to solve the problem that I'm working on and the solution that I've thought of is more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I haven't read the whole question, but it looks like you want to create a comparitor.  Have you checked out the Ruby [Comparable mixin module, linked here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html)?

Comment: Have you considered tossing your data into a database and letting it do the heavy lifting? Even SQLite would eat this stuff up.

Comment: I have used the comparable mixin already.  What I need to figure out is how that interacts with hashing?  Or maybe it doesn't matter that was part of I was wondering.

Comment: @muistooshort I am doing this for a one time things to process about a few million lines of text data in some several thousand log files.  So it's enough data that it's worth writing a script to parse, but not enough to justify using a database, at least I don't think it would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define: Hash#has_keys?
class Hash
    def has_keys? *args
        args.all?{|k| self.keys.include? k } unless self.keys.empty?
        # returns true if hash has all keys
        # returns false otherwise
        # returns nil if the hash is empty?
    end
end
```

not too sure about the rest.